# Learning more things about dependecies and repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dependencies

A month ago I moved from Windows to Ubuntu. While using Ubuntu I notice some things about installing software. I've read some installation guides about installing software, and been curious about two things: the first thing is the dependencies and the second one is the repositories.

I've search over the internet, and by definition I found this:

- A dependency is a file that something you are trying to install requires.
- A software repository is a storage location from which software packages are retrieved for installation.

But still I do have some questions.

1. Do I really need this two things as always? Why?
2. How can I identify which and what repositories and dependencies to use?
3. What things must I remember before installing dependencies and repositories?
4. Is there a good book to read about these two things?
5. Another option to deal with aside from using terminal? Should I use software center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repositories serve several purpose :

- every program from an "official" repository has been validated by canonical. It is thus considered safe for your system (not a malware).
- repositories allow to notify users when an update is ready. Your system is automatically up to date with new features and security releases.

To answer your questions :

1. Not necessarily. For instance, a `.deb` file can be installed without a repository (just download the file, and use `dpkg -i file.deb` to install it)
2. You can read the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) about this. There are default repositories from canonical, but you can also add custom repositories if you need some other resources. Dependencies are shown automatically when you try to install a package.
3. If you are invoking the update manager from the terminal, be careful about which options you use. For instance, `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` are fairly harmless, but option like `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt-get autoremove` can break your distro in some occasions.
   Also, always run `apt-get update` before upgrading your system or after you modified your repositories information.
4. I don't know of any. I learnt from reading the [official documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) & practice.
5. All package managers do about the same thing, the interface and some functionalities change. Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76/whats-the-difference-between-package-managers) for more details about the differences between them.

Comment: Can I see the default repositories through canonical official website? If it's not in the official website where can I see default repositories?

Comment: @Ian024 reading from the link of my point n°2, your current repositories addresses are stored in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I believe by default the only repository is the `main` one. Also, if you want to visualize your repositories in a GUI instead ofgoing through editing the `sources.list` file, have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)