# Unable to install KVM on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install KVM on Ubuntu 16.04, but I am getting stuck at very beginning.
I am unable to find the packages. Can someone help me? I did `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libvirt-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package qemu-kvm
E: Package 'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 5):

First make sure that all repositories are enabled, open Software & Updates and mark all sources :

[image: software]

Now open a terminal and execute the following commands to install all the packages needed :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qemu qemu-kvm
```

When you additionally want to use a GUI for the KVM virtualization environment, execute this :

```
sudo apt install virt-manager
```

Additional information : `qemu-kvm` depends on the appropriate `qemu-system-$arch` package, which gets automatically installed alongside when installing the `qemu` meta package. The very same is valid for the `libvirt-bin` package and all other `qemu` and `libvirt` related packages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as qemu-kvm is concerned you can find the package [here,](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/qemu-kvm) select your architecture, download and install it with the [package manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76/whats-the-difference-between-package-managers) of your choice. [aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get) is good at resolving dependencies that you may or may nor be aware of and is a good choice for these tasks. libvirt-bin is also available for xenial (16.04) through the under-utilized [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libvirt-bin)

Sources:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

[What's the difference between package managers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76/whats-the-difference-between-package-managers)

[Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get)